# Correct way to use dialogs with jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-dialog

I can't find a right way to use dialogs in compose. For example I have a common bottom sheet dialog with options list. I created an `OptionsDialog` widget, `OptionsDialogState` (list of options like: title, icon and etc) and `rememberSaveable` function for this state. Created `LocalOptionDialogSate` with `compositionLocalOf`. I placed `OptionsDialog` in the root of my UI tree. Now I can easily call this dialog with custom options anywhere in my app via `LocalOptionDialogSate`. But I steel need to pass action lambda for each option. And there is a problem. I can't save/restore (`rememberSaveable`) state  with function properties. How do I need to pass actions block (like `() -> Unit`) to the dialog?

Comment: Can you provide sample code